# How to generate a Global Voronoi diagram?

Tags: python, spherical-geometry, voronoi-thiessen, antimeridian

Using arcMap, QGIS and similar software it is easy to create a non-global Voronoi diagram.

The resulting shapefile polygons however are showing weird behavior when crossing the -180 meridian or the poles. What tool can I use to create a globally consistent Voronoi diagram similar to [this](https://www.jasondavies.com/maps/voronoi/airports/) website? A code based solution (Python/Javascript) is also ok.

Data used to create Voronoi:

```
+----------+--------------+-------------+--+
| name     | x            | y           |  |
+----------+--------------+-------------+  +
| Miami    | -80.25551469 | 25.79555801 |  |
+----------+--------------+-------------+  +
| Boston   | -71.07082218 | 42.3585578  |  |
+----------+--------------+-------------+  +
| Honolulu | -157.8555857 | 21.30573449 |  |
+----------+--------------+-------------+--+
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545870/algorithm-to-compute-a-voronoi-diagram-on-a-sphere